# Where do I add functions in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm running through several tutorials, and I don't quiet undertand where I can write/put multiline functions?

Say I needed this filter function

```
const filter = {
  address: 'England',
  name: 'Mark'
};
let users = [{
    name: 'John',
    email: 'johnson@mail.com',
    age: 25,
    address: 'USA'
  },
  {
    name: 'Tom',
    email: 'tom@mail.com',
    age: 35,
    address: 'England'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mark',
    email: 'mark@mail.com',
    age: 28,
    address: 'England'
  }
];


users= users.filter(item => {
  for (let key in filter) {
    if (item[key] === undefined || item[key] != filter[key])
      return false;
  }
  return true;
});s
```

Where do I put it in React? Most tutorials are focused on App.js page, and the only thing i've learned was to add code here {in brackets}:

```
<div>
      <h3> {1+1} </h3>
</div>
```

However, it doesn't make sense/looks bulky and unreadable to add the function above just inside there? Or is that the correct way? I'm currently focused on learning Javascript and frontend React only at the moment (not backend).

Comment: You can place it wherever you want, it's really up to you. Just try to be consistent.

Comment: Will this function be used in many components or just a single one? If you are going to be using it in multiple places, you could either make a `Helpers.js` file that has all your helper functions, or a custom hook if it is more complicated and requires state. If you only need it in one component, you should put it in the file for that component.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you could use that function in React:

1. Define the function within the App.js file (inside the App component)
2. Call that function inside the JSX that you're returning

```
const App = () => {
   const yourFunction = () => {

    users.filter(function(item) {
    for (var key in filter) {
     if (item[key] === undefined || item[key] != filter[key])
      return false;
    }
      return true;
    });

   }

   return (
   <div>
    <h1>{yourFunction()}</h1>
   </div>
   );

}
```

It works the same way as putting javascript inside the JSX - it just runs what's inside the tags and in this case, that means running the function outside the returning JSX.

Comment: If the function doesn't use any of the component's variables, it doesn't need to be inside the component. Putting it inside the component will cause that code to have to be re-evaluated every time the state changes.

Comment: Oh fair point. I assumed that the function might be returning something that would need to be rendered inside the component, however if it's not being rendered then for sure, it doesn't need to be inside it.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it doesn't need to be inside it? If I copy const yourFunction to } and paste it above const App = () => { it runs an error: unexpected token?

Comment: It's not that the function doesn't need to be inside the component, it just does not need to be called in the JSX unless you're actually using the return value and rendering it inside the JSX. Like @Mike said, you can take yourFunction and paste it inside another js file and import it into the App.js file which will allow you to make the function reusable across other components. Then you would need to take the imported file and call the function that you've imported in to use it. From my knowledge, React doesn't have a specific guideline, it just depends on how you want to organize things.

Comment: Here's how I arrange things. Every component gets its own file. I try to make every component do only one thing. If it's doing too much, break it into a separate component. As for functions, if I reuse them, I put them in a Helpers file and import the functions I need. If I only use it in one component, I put it in the same file. If that function uses any of the component's state, it needs to go inside the component's declaration as a sub-function. If not, I put it in the same file, but as a separate function above the component's function declaration.

Comment: If you're getting a syntax error, you didn't do it right. You must have missed a brace or something.